# MySQL table date update gives 00/00/0000 12:00:00 am format in table

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I am updating datetime column in one table, but when update the column date save as 00/00/0000 12:00:00 am.

Here is Mysql query

update b_tasks set DEADLINE='28/12/2017 01:30:00 pm' where ID=4666 AND TITLE LIKE 'Perform demo%'.
And in PHP look like

```
$sql='update b_tasks set DEADLINE="'.$dtformat.'" where ID="'.$tid1.'" 
AND TITLE LIKE "Perform demo%"';
```

Comment: What is the type of your column ?

Comment: type of my column is datetime

Comment: that's invalid format use `YYYY-mm-dd` instead

Comment: but in table other date shows in dd/mm/yyyy format thats why I used this format

Comment: @Beginner thanks its working but am,pm not working properly its taking am instead of pm.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="update b_tasks set DEADLINE=STR_TO_DATE('".$dtformat."','%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') where ID='".$tid1."' 
AND TITLE LIKE 'Perform demo%'";
```

Try above query.

You need to use [**`STR_TO_DATE`**](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp), which convert your given format string to date.

If you don't want to use this function you can go with default format `'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS'`

This will help you.

Comment: i used default format but it taking am instead of pm

Comment: Then go ahead with `STR_TO_DATE()`..!!